# GPFlow multiple independent realizations of same GP, irregular sampling times/lengths

Tags: gpflow

In GPflow I have multiple time series and the sampling times are not aligned across time series, and the time series may have different length (longitudinal data). I assume that they are independent realizations from the same GP. What is the right way to handle this with svgp, and more generally with GPflow? Do i need to use coregionalization? The coregionalization notebook assumed correlated trajectories, while I want shared mean/kernel but independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `Coregion` kernel implemented in GPflow is what you can use for your problem.

Let's set up some data from the generative model you describe, with different lengths for the timeseries:

```py
import numpy as np
import gpflow
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Ns = [80, 90, 100]  # number of observations for three different realizations
Xs = [np.random.uniform(0, 10, size=N) for N in Ns]  # observation locations

# three different draws from the same GP:
k = gpflow.kernels.Matern52(variance=2.0, lengthscales=0.5)  # kernel

Ks = [k(X[:, None]) for X in Xs]
Ls = [np.linalg.cholesky(K) for K in Ks]
vs = [np.random.randn(N, 1) for N in Ns]
fs = [(L @ v).squeeze(axis=-1) for L, v in zip(Ls, vs)]
```

To actually set up the training data for the gpflow GP model:

```py
# output indicator for the observations: which timeseries is this?
os = [o * np.ones(N) for o, N in enumerate(Ns)]  # [0 ... 0, 1 ... 1, 2 ... 2]

# now assemble the three timeseries in single data set:
allX = np.concatenate(Xs)
allo = np.concatenate(os)
allf = np.concatenate(fs)
X = np.c_[allX, allo]
Y = allf[:, None]
assert X.shape == (sum(Ns), 2)
assert Y.shape == (sum(Ns), 1)
```

```py
# now let's set up a copy of the original kernel:
k2 = gpflow.kernels.Matern52(active_dims=[0])  # the same as k above, but with different hyperparameters

# and a Coregionalization kernel that effectively says they are all independent:
kc = gpflow.kernels.Coregion(output_dim=len(Ns), rank=1, active_dims=[1])
kc.W.assign(np.zeros(kc.W.shape))
kc.kappa.assign(np.ones(kc.kappa.shape))
gpflow.set_trainable(kc, False)  # we want W and kappa fixed
```

The `Coregion` kernel defines a covariance matrix B = W Wᵀ + diag(kappa), so by setting W=0 we prescribe zero correlations (independent realizations) and kappa=1 (actually the default) ensures that the variance hyperparameter of the copy of the original kernel remains interpretable.

Now construct the actual model and optimize hyperparameters:

```py
k2c = k2 * kc

m = gpflow.models.GPR((X, Y), k2c, noise_variance=1e-5)

opt = gpflow.optimizers.Scipy()
opt.minimize(m.training_loss, m.trainable_variables, compile=False)
```

which recovers the initial variance and lengthscale hyperparameters pretty well.

If you want to predict, you have to provide the extra "output" column in the `Xnew` argument to `m.predict_f()`, e.g. as follows:

```py
Xtest = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
Xtest_augmented = np.c_[Xtest, np.zeros_like(Xtest)]
f_mean, f_var = m.predict_f(Xtest_augmented)
```

(whether you set the output column to 0, 1, or 2 does not matter, as we set them all to be the same with our choice of `W` and `kappa`).

If your input was more than one-dimensional, you could set
`active_dims=list(range(X.shape[1] - 1))` for the first kernel(s) and `active_dims=[X.shape[1]-1]` for the `Coregion` kernel.

Comment: One more question: given that we have to fix the W, does that mean that we can't do multi-task GPs with independent realizations? I.e. each person is an independent multivariate irregularly sampled time series?